Custom Physics Engine::Impulse Based Contact Resolver::Facing Object crawling issue when doing Box vs Box Collision
I am trying to implement basic stable 3d physics engine, I was able to get collision phase working with SAT but when I am applying impulses on box vs box contact points, I face a crawling issue. Please see the video below,
ImpulseBasedSolver::Object Crawling issue
Here's the code for my approach :
https://github.com/ankitsinghkushwah/EklavyaEngine/blob/physics-improvements/EklavyaEngine/EkPhysics/Constraint.cpp
Line::26::ContactConstraint::Solve() -> applies impulse on contacts
Line::107::ContactConstraint::PostSolve() -> corrects position
I am doing 50 iterations in the video shared for ContactConstraint::Solve() and I don't think this can be solved by increasing the iteration count. I tried applying friction but it doesn't make much difference.
What is missing here? Thanks in advance.
